# Is it possible to force apache server to read root htaccess before going into subdirectory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a subdirectory in root (let's call it `/sub`) and `.htaccess` in root. If I call the following URL: `mywebsite.com/sub`, I get directly into subdirectory omitting `.htaccess` in root, so I wanted to ask whether it is possible to force server to read root `.htaccess` first before going to subdirectory (and make corresponding redirection if needed)?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: I have discovered that my redirection explicitly excluded directories which was unwanted (and seemed to be the root of my problem):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://redirectwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I removed the second line, but unfortunately I still get into my folder.

So to make it clear:

- when I go to `http://mywebsite.com/not-a-folder-in-root`, I am redirected to the new site correctly
- when I fo to `http://mywebsite.com/a-folder-in-root`, I don't get redirected and go instead to my subfolder's `index.php`

The latter is the behavior I want to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to do. First .htaccess files are read in the order in which they are found.

[How directives are read](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html#how)

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to
>   the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all
>   subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that
>   there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up.
>   Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a
>   .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found
>   in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those,
>   in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, or in the
>   main server configuration file itself.

So the htaccess file will always override the file in the root directory. However you can manipulate the Apache config file and specify directives in say a `Location` directive. You can specify certain rules and then it will take affect over .htaccess rule. See info below.

> As discussed in the documentation on Configuration Sections, .htaccess
>   files can override the  sections for the corresponding
>   directory, but will be overridden by other types of configuration
>   sections from the main configuration files. This fact can be used to
>   enforce certain configurations, even in the presence of a liberal
>   AllowOverride setting. For example, to prevent script execution while
>   allowing anything else to be set in .htaccess you can use:

```
<Directory "/www/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Location "/">
    Options +IncludesNoExec -ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Otherwise if you can't do that change because you don't have access, you would have to do all the rules in the `root` .htaccess file that also pertains to the sub folder which you can do instead of putting an .htaccess in the `sub` folder.

**Edit based on comment**

```
#just use this for all requests
RewriteRule (.*) http://redirectwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Or you can do all non-existent folders and that sub folder too
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://redirectwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir! You were right, my root .htaccess was read despite of my guess, but the problem is still present - instead of being redirected I go into folder. I posted an excerpt from my .htaccess to be clearer, maybe you want take a look.

Comment: You want to redirect to the new URL if the folder does or does not exist? I need to be clear.

Comment: I want to redirect in either case.

Comment: @haemhweg do you want to redirect both to the same redirect website?

Comment: Oh, then you don't need the conditions at all. Just redirect everything. Comment out the first 2 lines and try that.

Comment: See my update, you can either do everything or you can just include that one folder to redirect also.

Comment: I tried and it was no use, response always sends me into the folder if it exists, even if my .htaccess file is the one-liner you proposed, which I find very bizarre. According to the docs it should work.

Comment: Try that latest update, but make sure to clear your browser cache because 301's are cached by browsers so you may not be getting the most updated rules.

Comment: I usually use incognito windows to ensure that cache is cleared. And the issue is still present, with both options tried. Actually the first option should overwrite everything, shouldn't it?

Comment: I didn't mean for you to use both rules. Just one or the other, but something is weird. Try in a different browser. Are you sure the htaccess is working? Other things are working? Put random text and the top and it should cause 500 error if it's working.

Comment: I applied them separately. So it didn't work anyway. The only way for me to cope with this is either delete the folders or move them or rename or whatever and then it works.